# How can I insert an ng directive in dynamic HTML?

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-class

I'm using the mark tag to highlight text in dynamically created HTML.  I want to use one of two styles depending on a condition.

I am able to specify a CSS class this way:

```
<mark class='selected'>
```

But if I change this to use `ng-class` (without even adding my condition yet)...

```
<mark ng-class='selected'>
```

... the highlighting defaults back to the mark tag's default style and does not use my 'selected' class.

## Are `<mark>` and `ng-class` incompatible?

Edit: Here's the code which hopefully will help clarify the issue.

In my MVC controller I query the database and receive text.  I replace certain characters in the text with the mark tags to highlight the items the database has identified need to be highlighted, e.g.

```
fieldText = fieldText.Replace("\u0002","<mark>");
fieldText = fieldText.Replace("\u0003","</mark>");
```

This becomes part of the model passed to the template, which uses ng-bind-html to tie it to a span:

```
<span ng-class="{'selectedField': field.ID.startsWith($ctrl.fieldId) ||  $ctrl.fieldId == 'Type' + $ctrl.row.TxType}" id="field.ID" ng-click="$ctrl.elementClicked(field.ID)" ng-bind-html="$ctrl.format(field)"></span>
```

My CSS defines the style for `<`mark>:

```
 mark {
     background-color: yellow;
     color: black;
     padding: 0px;
     text-decoration:underline;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
```

This works as far as it goes.  But when the condition specified in the `<`span> tag shown above is true, I need to change the style of the `<`mark> text (and not to the same style as the rest of the span).  So I'm trying to define the text in the MVC code to set the style conditionally:

```
fieldText = fieldText.Replace("\u0002","<mark ng-class=\"{'markSelected': $ctrl.isSelected(field.ID, $ctrl.fieldId)}\">");
```

But when I do this, the marked text reverts to the default `<`mark>  system highlighting, ignoring both my mark style and my markSelected style.

Answer (score 0):

ng-class is a directive that expects an expression. If you wanted to always use the same class you could do something like

```
<mark ng-class="value = 'selected'">
```